# Access Gadiva filter result by index in Apache Arrow

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how I can access the elements of an array after a Gandiva filter operation.

I have linked a minimal example which I compile like this:

```
$ /usr/lib64/ccache/g++ -g -Wall -m64 -std=c++17 -pthread -fPIC \
      -I/opt/data-an/include  mwe.cc -o mwe \
      -L/opt/data-an/lib64 -lgandiva -larrow
```

and I then run the binary like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/data-an/lib64 ./mwe
```

Broadly this is what I was attempting (followed by excerpts from the MWE):

1. create a 5-element vector: 1, 3, 2, 4, 5

   ```cpp
   int num_records = 5;
   arrow::Int64Builder i64builder;
   ArrayPtr array0;

   EXPECT_OK(i64builder.AppendValues({1, 3, 2, 4, 5}));
   EXPECT_OK(i64builder.Finish(&array0));
   ```
2. use Gandiva to get even elements, indices: 2, 3

   ```cpp
   // schema for input fields
   auto field0 = field("f0", arrow::int64());
   auto schema = arrow::schema({field0});

   // even: f0 % 2 == 0
   auto field0_node = TreeExprBuilder::MakeField(field0);
   auto lit_2 = TreeExprBuilder::MakeLiteral(int64_t(2));
   auto remainder = TreeExprBuilder::MakeFunction("mod", {field0_node, lit_2}, int64());
   auto lit_0 = TreeExprBuilder::MakeLiteral(int64_t(0));
   auto even = TreeExprBuilder::MakeFunction("equal", {remainder, lit_0}, boolean());
   auto condition = TreeExprBuilder::MakeCondition(even);

   // input record batch
   auto in_batch = arrow::RecordBatch::Make(schema, num_records, {array0});

   // filter
   std::shared_ptr<Filter> filter;
   EXPECT_OK(Filter::Make(schema, condition, &filter));

   std::shared_ptr<SelectionVector> selected;
   EXPECT_OK(SelectionVector::MakeInt16(num_records, pool_, &selected));
   EXPECT_OK(filter->Evaluate(*in_batch, selected));
   ```
3. access the even elements in the original array by using the selection vector from the Gandiva filter as an index array

   ```cpp
   // std::cout << "array0[0]: " << array0->Value(0); // doesn't compile
   // error: ‘using element_type = class arrow::Array’ {aka ‘class
   // arrow::Array’} has no member named ‘Value’

   // downcast it to the correct derived class
   auto array0_cast = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<NumericArray<Int64Type>>(array0);
   std::cout << "array0[0]: " << array0_cast->Value(0) << std::endl;
   ```

But I can't seem to access the elements of the [selection vector](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/classgandiva_1_1_selection_vector.html).  Since it was declared as `std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>`, the `Value(..)` method isn't found.  Since I filled it with `SelectionVector::MakeInt16(..)`, I tried downcasting to `arrow::NumericArray<Int16Type>`, but that fails!  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```cpp
auto idx_arr_cast = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<NumericArray<Int16Type>>(idx_arr);
if (idx_arr_cast) {
  std::cout << "idx_arr[0]: " << idx_arr_cast->Value(0) << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cerr << "idx_arr_cast is a nullptr!" << std::endl;
}
```

I also have a related, but more general question.  Given an array, I can't find a way to access the elements (or iterate over them) if I don't know the exact type.  If I know the type, I can downcast, and use the likes of `Value(..)`, `GetValue(..)`, `GetString(..)`, etc.  That seems quite round about just to access the elements.  What am I missing?

**Note:** The complete MWE, along with a Makefile, can be cloned from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/suvayu/aa2d38cee82b97be76186ec00073fe10).

Comment: I strongly suggest asking this question (and future questions) on the dev@ mailing list instead of StackOverflow. Not many Arrow developers follow the tags here.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll repost on the dev list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectionVector` stores indices, so the type is `unsigned`, the following works:

```
auto arr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<NumericArray<UInt16Type>>(selected->ToArray());
```

Thanks to Ravindra on the Arrow dev list for [the answer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/arrow-dev/201812.mbox/%3C20181214145921.fjo73odrm2tgabar%40karna%3E).